# skippable-exception-classes in spring batch to skip only one row

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am new to spring batch , the csv file for example

```
Employee   Name Id age year
Department DeptName deptId desc
Department DeptName deptId desc
Employee   Name Id age year
Department DeptName deptId desc
Department DeptName deptId desc
```

This is my format

If that employer with name exists mysql will throw DataIntegrityViolationException

So i added

```
<batch:skippable-exception-classes>
<batch:include  class="org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException" />
</batch:skippable-exception-classes>
```

So this will skip the whole unit the corresponding Employer and Department records

what I have to do even if the Employee exists and throws this Exception

Then to continue with Department.

Comment: Do you have different processors for Employers and Departements?

Comment: No, If I create a separate processor and skip to next step?

Comment: Create a custom processor, check for employer in database and skip it (returning null) if found. Else return the Employer DTO and pass it to writer

Comment: When it's huge record's to process, to check each Employee exists will make the process more heavy right? what If I try to write in an error file only the duplicate Object, then onSkipInWrite I maybe getting Employee transient object, Any possibility to get Employee item

Comment: I usually avoid as much as possible exception handling if I can reach the same goal with an item processor and a cache (to avoid multiple database hits for same object). If you wanna, try to catch write error; you have the target object in onSkipItmeInWrite.

Comment: For onSkipInProcess I will get Item, but for onSkipInWrite returns transient object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135679/discussion-between-cork-kochi-and-luca-basso-ricci).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use item classifier

```
public class ItemTypeClassifier {
    @Classifier
    public String classify(Item item) {
        return item.getType();// returns "Employee", "Department"
    }
}
```

Then a router implementation with two different item writer, one for employee and one for department.

```
<bean id="classifier"  class="org.springframework.batch.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
    <property name="routerDelegate">
        <bean class="ItemTypeClassifier" />
    </property>
    <property name="matcherMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="Employee" value-ref="emplyeeItemWriter" />
            <entry key="Department" value-ref="departmentItemWriter" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then

```
<bean id="ItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter">
    <property name="classifier" ref="classifier" />
</bean>
```

Now that you have two different writer, you can run two steps inside your job by defining two separate skippable exceptions configuration for them.